# Cardinality of a set with a recurrence relation.

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, polynomials, recurrence-relations, cardinals

Let $A = \left\{ f\in \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{C} \mid \forall n\in \mathbb{N}. f(n+3) + 3f(n+1) = f(n+2)+f(n) \right\}$

What is $\left|A\right|$?

Well, I tried to treat $f$ as a recurrence relation and hence, the characteristic polynomial is: $x^3 + 3x = x^2 + 1$.

The roots for this polynomial [aren't "nice"](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3-x%5E2%2b3x-1=0).

So, I guess I should do something different, though it seems very natural to use characteristic polynomial here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This recurrence defines $f(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ given $f(0), f(1), f(2)$. For each set of those it gives a different function, so...